# Why can't H2 create this table?

Tags: java, h2

Why can't H2 create this table?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCORE_CARD")
public final class ScoreCard implements Serializable {

    public static final int DEFAULT_SCORE = 10;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2504167837465532618L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CARD_ID")
    private final Long cardId;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private final Long userId;

    @Column(name = "ATTEMPT_ID")
    private final Long attemptId;

    @Column(name = "SCORE_TS")
    private final Long scoreTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "SCORE")
    private final int score;

    @Column(name = "CORRECT")
    private final boolean correct;

    public ScoreCard(Long cardId, Long userId, Long attemptId, Long scoreTimestamp, int score,
                     boolean correct) {
        this.cardId = cardId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.attemptId = attemptId;
        this.scoreTimestamp = scoreTimestamp;
        this.score = correct ? DEFAULT_SCORE : 0;
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    public ScoreCard() {
        this(null, null, null, null, 0, false);
    }

    public ScoreCard(Long userId, Long attemptId, boolean correct) {
        this(null, userId, attemptId, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, correct);
    }

    public Long getCardId() {
        return cardId;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Long getAttemptId() {
        return attemptId;
    }

    public Long getScoreTimestamp() {
        return scoreTimestamp;
    }

    public long getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }

}
```

here's the application.properties:

```
####### START H2 #######

# Creates the database in a file
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/projects-data/social-multiplication/gamification;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

# Shows the SQL in console
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

####### END H2 #######
```

I've tried changing the `@GeneratedValue` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` but it didn't work. I have many other tables just like this one which get generated just fine... I don't get why this doesn't.

I get an SQLGrammarException when trying to create this table.

**EDIT** stack trace

```
2023-04-08 23:35:23.046 DEBUG 14292 --- [  restartedMain] m.b.g.GamificationApplication            : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23
2023-04-08 23:35:23.047  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] m.b.g.GamificationApplication            : The following 1 profile is active: "local"
2023-04-08 23:35:23.153  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-04-08 23:35:23.154  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-04-08 23:35:24.566  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-08 23:35:24.652  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 71 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-08 23:35:26.309  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2023-04-08 23:35:26.323  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-04-08 23:35:26.323  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2023-04-08 23:35:26.492  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-08 23:35:26.492  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3337 ms
2023-04-08 23:35:26.545  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-08 23:35:26.939  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-08 23:35:26.952  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:~/projects-data/social-multiplication/gamification'
2023-04-08 23:35:27.198  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-08 23:35:27.311  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
2023-04-08 23:35:27.623  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-04-08 23:35:27.809  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-04-08 23:35:28.017  WARN 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.java.JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry  : HHH000481: Encountered Java type [interface microservices.book.gamification.domain.badge.Badge] for which we could not locate a JavaTypeDescriptor and which does not appear to implement equals and/or hashCode.  This can lead to significant performance problems when performing equality/dirty checking involving this Java type.  Consider registering a custom JavaTypeDescriptor or at least implementing equals/hashCode.
2023-04-08 23:35:28.499  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-08 23:35:28.515  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-08 23:35:29.534  WARN 14292 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-04-08 23:35:30.832  WARN 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2023-04-08 23:35:30.907  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-04-08 23:35:30.909  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2023-04-08 23:35:31.003  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#7261045c:0/SimpleConnection@7c3c110e [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 56088]
2023-04-08 23:35:31.094  INFO 14292 --- [  restartedMain] m.b.g.GamificationApplication            : Started GamificationApplication in 8.787 seconds (JVM running for 9.656)
2023-04-08 23:35:31.104  INFO 14292 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2023-04-08 23:35:31.180 DEBUG 14292 --- [ntContainer#0-1] m.book.gamification.event.EventHandler   : MultiplicationSolvedEvent: MultiplicationSolvedEvent{userId=3, multiplicationResultAttemptId=1, correct=false}
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
2023-04-08 23:35:31.239  WARN 14292 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90036, SQLState: 90036
2023-04-08 23:35:31.239 ERROR 14292 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-214]
2023-04-08 23:35:31.259  WARN 14292 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'void microservices.book.gamification.event.EventHandler.handleMultiplicationSolved(microservices.book.gamification.event.MultiplicationSolvedEvent) throws org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:272) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:209) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:148) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1670) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1589) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1577) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1568) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1512) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:994) [spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:941) [spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:85) [spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1319) [spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1225) [spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [call next value for hibernate_sequence]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at microservices.book.gamification.service.impl.GameServiceImpl.newAttemptForUser(GameServiceImpl.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at microservices.book.gamification.event.EventHandler.handleMultiplicationSolved(EventHandler.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:77) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:263) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:534) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSequence(Parser.java:8471) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermWithIdentifier(Parser.java:5347) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermWithIdentifier(Parser.java:5217) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4901) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3398) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:3385) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:3350) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3132) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:3053) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCall(Parser.java:6980) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:765) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    ... 67 common frames omitted

2023-04-08 23:35:31.266  INFO 14292 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2023-04-08 23:35:31.873  INFO 14292 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutdown ignored - container is already stopped
2023-04-08 23:35:31.881  INFO 14292 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-08 23:35:31.887  INFO 14292 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-04-08 23:35:31.899  INFO 14292 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Line 46,47 of GameServiceImpl.java:

```
ScoreCard scoreCard = new ScoreCard(userId, attemptId, correct);
scoreCardRepository.save(scoreCard);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

i'm assuming you do not have sequence generated for

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CARD_ID")
    private final Long cardId;
```

try update it to

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "card_sequence",
            sequenceName = "card_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "card_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            name = "CARD_ID",
            updatable = false
    )
```

Comment: didn't work, I get the same error

Comment: are you running with spring boot, or its java ee?

Comment: Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23, Java 8

Comment: have you imported spring-data-jpa as dependency ?

Comment: just tested your code, it works just fine, you can check it [here](https://github.com/hammafataka/st_ov_answer)

Comment: mmmm so that means thre's something very specific to my project which breaks it

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: yeah no, I just found it. It's the line where I specify the db file location:
```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/projects-data/social-multiplication/gamification;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE```
I commented it and it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253056/discussion-between-idk-and-mohammed-fataka).